# Find url name in XML document

Tags: c#, html, xml

I need to search an XMLdocument for a specific url name for my website.

This is so that when the user navigates my site, whatever page they are on will dictate what the side menu looks like. Here is my code so far:

```
var urlName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Request.Url.AbsolutePath);

XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/menu.xml"));
xmlDocument.SelectNodes("//*[contains(text(), 'urlName')]");
```

Once found I would like the result to return that websites node and parent node.

```
<menu type="personal">
  <L1 shortName="Something here" id="/personal/something-here.aspx" url="../personal/something-here.aspx" regions="123">
    <L2 shortName="anything here" id="/personal/anything-here.aspx" url="../personal/anything-here.aspx" regions="123">
      <L3 shortName="everything here" id="/personal/everything-here.aspx" url="../personal/everything-here.aspx" regions="123"/>
    </L2>
    <L2 shortName="something" id="/personal/something.aspx" url="../personal/something.aspx" regions="123">
      <L3 shortName="anything" id="/personal/anything.aspx" url="../personal/anything.aspx" regions="123" />
      <L3 shortName="everything" id="/personal/everything.aspx" url="../personal/everything.aspx" regions="123" />
    </L2>
  </L1>
</menu>
```

Comment: can you add a snippet of the file "menu.xml" so we can see its structure?

Comment: http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html

Comment: are you trying to find the `shortName`s? In what level are you trying to find it, `L1`, `L2`, `L3` or all three?

Comment: No, not the shortName, I get the filename and it could either search the id or url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all who helped, however I found another way that works perfectly.  Thanks again.

```
        XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();

        xmlDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/menu.xml"));

        XmlNodeList levelOneElements = xmlDocument.SelectNodes("root/menu[contains(@type,'" + Title.Text.ToLower() +  "')]/L1");

        for (int i = 0; i < levelOneElements.Count; i++)
        {
            XmlNode levelOne = levelOneElements.Item(i);
            if (levelOne.OuterXml.Contains(_menu))
            {
                _index = i;
                break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use Linq. This retrieves the element name of the parent.

```
    var urlName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Request.Url.AbsolutePath);

    XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/menu.xml"));
    var url = (from p in doc.Descendants().Elements()
               where p.Attribute("url").Value == urlName 
               select p.Parent.Name.LocalName).FirstOrDefault();
```

You may need to use `where p.Attribute("id").Value == urlName` instead of url, but you can work that out!

If you want the entire element, change to  `select p.Parent).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: I initially thought of using something similar to this however it is not returning anything.  When I am debugging I get "Enumeration yielded no results"  Any thoughts?

Comment: Yes.  Once someone visits the page then a jquery function fires and edits a side menu accordingly.

Comment: for example if they go to a page about cars "cars.aspx" then the cars item in the menu is highlighted.  Then if they go to a page about contacts "contact-us.aspx then the contact us is highlighted.  I just need to find a way to search for the corresponding site in the xml file.  Once I have that then the jquery portion should be easy (hopefully).

Comment: Just its node location and/or parent node, for example L3 would correspond to L2.  Sorry for making this difficult.  I am not very good at explaining things.

Comment: @Chris, updated my answer, see if that helps. Do you expect to always get an answer, if so change from FirstOrDefault() to just First. I must point out, you could have easily used real data here and had a quicker response from other people!